# ASP.NET MVC Jquery Validation Returns True Always

Tags: jquery-validate

Why is it when the forms show that the validation has not passed, the return value for the following code still returns true. The forms are indicating that the validated fields are in error but the code below adds the wait no matter what because the valid method returns true.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[type=submit]").click(function () {
            if ($("input[type=submit]").valid() == true || $(this).attr("name") == "SaveDraft")
                {
                  $("*").css("cursor", "wait");
                 }
        });
    });
```

This is basic unobtrusive validation built into .NET.

Answer (score 0):

I had to reference the element directly instead of how I was doing it.

$("#MySubmitbutton").

instead of 
$("input[type=submit]").